# Is the Balazard-Saias-Yor integral non-positive?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

Define $$I= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\log|\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|}{\frac{1}{4}+t^2} \mathrm{d}t.$$ Balazard, Saias and Yor showed that the Riemann Hypothesis is equivalent to the statement that $I=0$. It seems to me that $I\leq 0$. **Is this result known or significant ?**  Because it appears to be quite trivial to me.

Indeed, from

\begin{equation}
\zeta(s) = \frac{s}{s-1}-s\int_{1}^{\infty} \lbrace x \rbrace x^{-s-1} \mathrm{d}x
\end{equation} valid for $\Re(s)>0$ where $\lbrace y \rbrace$ denotes the fractional part of $y$, one easily finds that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists some constant $\alpha$ (dependent on $\epsilon$) such that
\begin{equation}
|\zeta(1/2 + it)| \leq \Big(\frac{1}{4}+t^2\Big)^{\alpha+\epsilon t^2}
\end{equation} for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$. Define $0<\gamma_1 < \gamma_2<\gamma_3 < \cdots $ to be the infinitely many positive zeros of $\zeta(s)$ on the line $\Re(s)=\frac{1}{2}$ and let $\delta>0$ be some real number. Consider
\begin{equation}
I_{\delta} = \Bigg(\int_{\delta-\gamma_1}^{0} + \int_{0}^{\gamma_{1}-\delta} \Bigg)\frac{\log |\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|}{\frac{1}{4}+t^2} \mathrm{d}t + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Bigg(\int_{\delta-\gamma_{n+1}}^{-\gamma_{n}-\delta} + \int_{\gamma_{n}+ \delta}^{\gamma_{n+1}-\delta} \Bigg)\frac{\log |\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|}{\frac{1}{4}+t^2} \mathrm{d}t. 
\end{equation} Note that by our definition of $\gamma_n$, $\log|\zeta(1/2 + it)|$ is well-defined on $[0, \gamma_{1}-\delta], [\delta-\gamma_{1},0], [\gamma_{n} + \delta, \gamma_{n+1}-\delta]$ and $[\delta-\gamma_{n+1}, -\gamma_{n}-\delta]$ for every positive integer $n$, thus we can insert the inequality for $|\zeta(1/2 + it)|$ into the preceding equation and obtain 
\begin{equation}
I_{\delta} \leq \Bigg(\int_{\delta-\gamma_1}^{0} + \int_{0}^{\gamma_{1}-\delta} \Bigg)\frac{(\alpha + \epsilon t^2)\log(\frac{1}{4}+t^2)}{\frac{1}{4}+t^2} \mathrm{d}t + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Bigg(\int_{\delta-\gamma_{n+1}}^{-\gamma_{n}-\delta} + \int_{\gamma_{n}+ \delta}^{\gamma_{n+1}-\delta} \Bigg)\frac{(\alpha + \epsilon t^2)\log(\frac{1}{4}+t^2)}{\frac{1}{4}+t^2} \mathrm{d}t
\end{equation} hence
\begin{align}
\lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0^+} I_{\delta} &\leq \Bigg(\int_{-\gamma_1}^{0} + \int_{0}^{\gamma_{1}} \Bigg)\frac{(\alpha + \epsilon t^2)\log(\frac{1}{4}+t^2)}{\frac{1}{4}+t^2} \mathrm{d}t + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Bigg(\int_{-\gamma_{n}+1}^{-\gamma_{n}} + \int_{\gamma_{n}}^{\gamma_{n+1}} \Bigg)\frac{(\alpha + \epsilon t^2)\log(\frac{1}{4}+t^2)}{\frac{1}{4}+t^2} \mathrm{d}t \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(\alpha + \epsilon t^2) \log(\frac{1}{4}+t^2)}{\frac{1}{4}+t^2} \mathrm{d}t \\
&=0
\end{align} since $\epsilon$ is *arbitrary* and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\log(\frac{1}{4}+t^2)}{\frac{1}{4}+t^2} \mathrm{d}t=0$. Notice that from our earlier expression for $I_\delta$ that we have $\lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0^+} I_{\delta} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\log |\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|}{\frac{1}{4}+t^2} \mathrm{d}t$, thus from from the last inequality we deduce that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\log |\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|}{\frac{1}{4}+t^2} \mathrm{d}t \leq 0$, as earlier mentioned.

Comment: The integral is a sum over the zeros on $\Re(s) > 1/2$ with each term of the same sign and non-zero. That's why the RH is true iff $ I = 0$

Comment: @Reuns, you're saying ''the integral is a sum over the zeros on $\Re(s)>1/2$ with each term of the same **sign**.'' Which sign is this ? Positive or negative ? Because if it's positive, then notice that the result $I\leq 0$ would prove the RH...

Comment: http://iml.univ-mrs.fr/~balazard/pdfdjvu/9.pdf

Comment: @reuns, i can't believe this, thanks !!!!

Comment: @reuns, in other words you're saying the RH is equivalent to the statement that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\log(0.25 + t^2)}{0.25 + t^2} \mathrm{d}t=0$. This is elementary and is known independently of the RH. See Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Sorry I meant $\log |\zeta|$ and that if your sign isn't the expected one it means your argument isn't correct

Comment: @reuns, according to your very own comment, the ''expected'' sign under the RH is $I \leq 0$, which is exactly what i  have. You can tell me where the argument isn't correct, if you see any.

Comment: Ok $\zeta(1/2+it) = O( (1/4+t^2)^a)$ but the constant isn't $\le 1$ as $\zeta(1/2) = -1.46$. With $\log |\zeta(1/2+it)| \le \log C (1/4+t^2)^a = \log C + a \log(1/4+t^2)$ it doesn't work anymore and you have just bounded above $\sum\log |\rho/(1-\rho)|$

Comment: @reuns, i'm not getting what you're saying. Are you saying that the inequality $$|\zeta(1/2 + it)|\leq(0.25+t^2)^{\alpha + \epsilon t^2}$$ is wrong ? In any case, your criticism should be based on this inequality, since it is the basis of all later arguments.

Comment: Sure take $t=0$ and the $\epsilon t^2$ is useless, all you are saying is that $|\zeta(1/2+it)| \le C (1/4+t^2)^a$ with $a > 0, C > 0$ and your argument fails as $C > 1$

Comment: No, the $\epsilon t^2$ is NOT useless because it grows as $t$ becomes large. Don't impose your misinterpretations on the question. Infact, i put the $\epsilon t^2$ specifically for the reason that $|\zeta(1/2)|\sim 1.46$.

Comment: $t^2$ makes the integral diverge so my interpretation is correct. $|\zeta(1/2+it)| \le C (1/4+t^2)^a, C > 1, a > 0$ gives a bound ( kind of bound that we also know from the density of zeros). And you don't need to split the integral between the zeros in the critical line since the $\log$ singuarities are integrable. Also for the RH you should always consider those Dirichlet series with functional equation but no Euler product for which the RH fails.

Comment: 1/2) No, the $\epsilon t^2$ is NOT useless because it grows as $t$ becomes large. Don't impose your misinterpretations on the question. Infact, i put the $\epsilon t^2$ specifically for the reason that $|\zeta(1/2)|\sim 1.46$. Infact, we can take $\alpha$ to be such that $|\zeta(1/2)|=(1/4)^(\alpha)$, note that $|\zeta(1/2 + it)|$ is decreasing on $(-2, 2)$, whereas $(0.25+t^2)^{\alpha + \epsilon t^2}$ is increasing on the same region, hence the inequality $$|\zeta(1/2 + it)|\leq (0.25+t^2)^{\alpha + \epsilon t^2}$$ holds on $(-2, 2)$.

Comment: 2/2) For $|t|\geq 2$, an even stronger result that $|\zeta(1/2 + it)| \leq t\log t^2$ holds.

Comment: The factor $t^2$ would make the integral diverge if we didn't have an arbitrary $\epsilon$. In any case, i can simply replace $t^2$ can by ANY increasing, bounded even function of $t$, say $(\tan^{-1}t)^2$.

Comment: As for the case of zeta functions whose analogue of the RH is false, note that my argument can be viewed as an extension of the Balazard et al paper. Thus one should ask whether the analogue of the Balazard et al result also holds for such Dirichlet functions.

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\log|F(\frac{1}{2}+it)|}{\frac{1}{4}+t^2} \mathrm{d}t= \sum_{\Re(\beta) > 1/2} \log |\beta/(1-\beta)|$ (and most theorems such as the density of zeros) holds for any linear combination of Dirichlet L-function, and RH fails for those that are not Dirichlet L-functions. Clearly there is no simple way to find a bound which applies only to $|\zeta(1/2+it)|$ and not to  $|\zeta(1/2+it)+L(1/2+it,\chi)|$. That's why trying to repair the divergence of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{t^2}{\frac{1}{4}+t^2} \mathrm{d}t$ is hopeless

Comment: What specifically is $F$ ? And can you give me a reference of this result ?

Comment: Actually, a bound that applies to $|\zeta(1/2 + it)|$ will CERTAINLY NOT apply for $|\zeta(1/2 + it) + L(1/2 + it, \chi)|$ for ALL $t\in \mathbb{R}$ (consider $t=0$). This is why i said earlier on, don't impose your misinterpretations/misunderstandings on the question. And note that the largest contribution to the Balazard integral comes from $t=0$ on the integrand. In any case, i usually want to judge an argument basing on its merits/demerits, not to appeal to historical beliefs that are also questionable themselves.