# $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\log|\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|}{\frac{1}{4}+t^2}dt$ where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\log|\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|}{\frac{1}{4}+t^2}dt$$
where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function. It is known by Balazard Saias and Yor Paper that I is integrable and $0\leq I<\infty$.

Since by Schwarz Reflection principle, integrand is an even function, so,
$$I= 2\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log|\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|}{\frac{1}{4}+t^2}dt  $$
Let, $0<t_1<t_2<t_3<...<t_n<t_{n+1}<...$ be infinitely many zeros of $\zeta(s)$ on the critical line $\Re(s)=1/2$.
Define ,$ \ t_0=0$.
$$I= 2 \ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{t_n}^{t_{n+1}} \frac{\log|\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|}{\frac{1}{4}+t^2}dt  $$
Let, $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrarily small.
Define,
$$I_{\epsilon}=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{t_n+\frac{\epsilon}{4}}^{t_{n+1}-\frac{\epsilon}{4}} \frac{\log|\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|}{\frac{1}{4}+t^2}dt  $$
Note that $|\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|$ is non zero on $[t_n+\frac{\epsilon}{4},t_{n+1}-\frac{\epsilon}{4}]$ $\forall n\geq 0$, so $\log|\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|$ is well defined on $[t_n+\frac{\epsilon}{4},t_{n+1}-\frac{\epsilon}{4}]$ $\forall n\geq 0$

**Question 1** Prove that
$$2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^{+}}\int_{t_n+\frac{\epsilon}{4}}^{t_{n+1}-\frac{\epsilon}{4}} \frac{\log|\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|}{\frac{1}{4}+t^2}dt =I $$
**Question 2** Prove that
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} I_{\epsilon}=I$$

Do I need Dominated Convergence Theorem?..

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120609/discussion-on-question-by-ashyln-brooke-int-infty-infty-frac-log-zet).

Answer (score 2):

As there were many comments and the situation seems to still be confused for you, I will address some issues in one post.

(edited later per comments below); the crux of the matter here is that the statement (existing in the question version as of March 8, screenshot available upon request):

"Note that $|\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|$ is non zero on $[t_n+\frac{\epsilon}{4},t_{n+1}-\frac{\epsilon}{4}]$ $\forall n\geq 0$ so $\log|\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|$ is well defined etc" is incorrect.

Both questions $1,2$ (as stated now) are incorrect as formulated for the simple fact that given $\epsilon >0$ fixed, (at least and if current conjectures are true, actually all for some $n(\epsilon)$ on) some of the intervals $[t_n+\frac{\epsilon}{4},t_{n+1}-\frac{\epsilon}{4}]$ are ill-defined in the sense that the left end is higher than the right end, while even if we reverse them, infinitely many such intervals will eventually still contain other RZ roots, so there is no way to define a union of intervals as you want to avoid roots of RZ.

(for once $\liminf (t_{n+1}-t_n) =0$ showing first assertion above, and for another if we could have a union of intervals whether $[t_n+\frac{\epsilon}{4},t_{n+1}-\frac{\epsilon}{4}]$ or $[t_{n+1}-\frac{\epsilon}{4}, t_n+\frac{\epsilon}{4}]$ depending which end is higher, avoiding roots it would follow that roots are spaced at least $\epsilon/4$ apart and that trivially gives a contradiction with Selberg's theorem that there at least $cT\log T$ roots on the critical line with height up to $T$).

This being said I truly have no clue about the purpose of these questions since if one wants to prove that $I$ exists is finite and non-negative, there are various rigorous ways of doing it - the Balazard et others paper gives one based on the theory of Hardy spaces, another way can be given by constructing a domain where $\log \zeta$ is analytic by excluding horizontal segments ending at zeroes and using Cauchy to move the path of integration to infinity etc. Those methods give the full expression of $I$ in terms of a sum of non-trivial zeroes with real part greater than $1/2$ which can be easily estimated above by known results to a fairly small number, so $0 \le I < \delta$ with RH true iff $I=0$.

If one just wants to show that $I$ exists and is finite, that has nothing really to do with the theory of RZ beyond trivial estimates in the strip of the type $|\zeta(s)| \le C|s|, \Re s \ge \sigma >0$, the local form of holomorphic functions at zeroes and Lebesgue integration theory as one can trivially show that $\frac{log|\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|}{\frac{1}{4}+t^2}$ is integrable on $[M,N]$ for $M>N \ge 0$ and that $\lim_{M >N \to {\infty}}\int_{N}^{M} \frac{log|\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|}{\frac{1}{4}+t^2}dt=0$ which gives that $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{log|\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|}{\frac{1}{4}+t^2}dt$ exists and is finite; actually pretty much same proof and estimates show that $ \frac{log|\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|}{\frac{1}{4}+t^2}$ is absolutely integrable on $[0, \infty)$ though of course one doesn't have a neat form of the integral of the absolute value anymore.

Comment: Your answer is nice. What do you mean by saying that question is true by the fact that RZ is conjugate invariant?

Comment: it is a typo since the questions changed; will edit

Comment: How is question 1 trivially true?

Comment: question 1 is incorrect - a while ago (at least if I remember correctly as there were many discussions) question 1 was if the integral $I$ is twice the integral on $[0, \infty)$ as stated now both questions $1,2$ are just ill-defined, hence incorrect for that reason

Comment: But by using Indicator function and By dominated convergence theorem we can prove question 1 as true.?

Comment: there is no way to coherently define $I_{\epsilon}$ for a fixed $\epsilon$; one needs to cut smaller and smaller intervals near the $t_n$ as $n \to \infty$

Comment: Dont you think that it is trivial by DCT that $$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^{+}}\int_{t_n+\frac{\epsilon}{4}}^{t_{n+1}-\frac{\epsilon}{4}} \frac{\log|\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|}{\frac{1}{4}+t^2}dt =   \int_{t_n}^{t_{n+1}} \frac{\log|\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|}{\frac{1}{4}+t^2}dt  $$

Comment: that is correct for $\epsilon < \epsilon(n)$ so yes in the limit, but what is not correct is that $I_{\epsilon}$ is coherent as is now (meaning for fixed $\epsilon$ and all $n$ - for example infinitely many such integrals will superpose, there will be infinitely many zeroes of $\zeta$ inside them etc and then one just can use $(t_n, t_{n+1})$ dispense with a limit in $\epsilon$ etc; one needs to cut at some large $N$ and have a finite sum which is precisely what my answer indicates and how these things are usually done

Comment: what do we mean by saying that $\epsilon<\epsilon(n)$?. So are the two integrals equal for all $\epsilon$?

Comment: LHS integral is coherent and proper for $\epsilon < \epsilon(n)$; one can of course make it an improper integral like $I$ and accept that we allow integrals, where the lower bound, is bigger than the higher bound as usually by changing sign, but again these issues defeat the whole purpose of the question (to avoid singularities in the integrand) plus raising issues about the superposition;

Comment: simply put the statement $\log|\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|$ is well defined on $[t_n+\frac{\epsilon}{4},t_{n+1}-\frac{\epsilon}{4}]$ for all $n \ge 0$ is incorrect; what is correct is that it holds only for $n <n(\epsilon)$

Comment: $log|\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|$ is well defined for all $t\in[t_n+\frac{\epsilon}{4},t_{n+1}-\frac{\epsilon}{4}]$. Because in this interval we don't have the zeros $t_n $ and $t_{n+1}$

Comment: no because for fixed $\epsilon$ there will always be an $n(\epsilon)$ where we will start having zeroes in that interval at least for some $n \ge n(\epsilon)$ (and actually in infinitely many such intervals)

Comment: See this- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3020198/is-the-balazard-saias-yor-integral-non-positive?r=SearchResults. Here he/she has defined the integral this way.

Comment: posts on MSE are not math proofs and if a user posts something, it doesn't make it true; here we argue about this post and I am of course always open to arguments pertinent to this post and my answer, clearly stated here and not dubious references that didn't undergo peer review at a reputed journal

Comment: as an aside the linked post is wrong for other reasons (pointed in comments there), as the stuff in the discussion here ( taking zero free intervals on the critical line where $\zeta$ is non-zero) can be easily finessed by cutting at some $N$ etc; pretty much any argument that uses an infinite sum can be restated in a rigorous finite sum limit as I noted in my answer; the question as usual is what the purpose is and the linked post leads toward another fake proof of RH

Comment: Please read my answer. Is it correct?